# How to send mails with an attachment(s) (.csv etc) in shell scripting (ksh)

Tags: bash, shell, scripting, ksh

I need to send a mail with attachment (`.csv`) by using a script (ksh).

Can someone please suggest the command/syntax?

Answer (score 2):

```
mail -a /path/to/file -s "some subject" your.email@example.com
```

Comment: db2 "export to /tmp/filename.csv of del select * from orders where orderid in(123,345,456,341)" | mail -a /tmp/filename.csv -s "some subject" your.email@example.com